# Using QGIS Geometry Generator to get rectangle from point?

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

I would like to translate a point (from a point layer) to a rectangle polygon using the new Geometry Generator from QGIS 2.14.

I know the length and the height of the resulting rectangle. The point should be the centroid.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

While you can't do maths inside the WKT representation - you can use geom_from_wkt to turn a text string with maths in it back into a geometry. Something like:

```
geom_from_wkt( 
'POLYGON(('|| 
(x( centroid( $geometry) ) + 0.5)||' '||(y( centroid( $geometry) ) + 0.5)||','||
(x( centroid( $geometry) ) + 0.5)||' '||(y( centroid( $geometry) ) - 0.5)||','||
(x( centroid( $geometry) ) - 0.5)||' '||(y( centroid( $geometry) ) - 0.5)||','||
(x( centroid( $geometry) ) - 0.5)||' '||(y( centroid( $geometry) ) + 0.5)||','||
(x( centroid( $geometry) ) + 0.5)||' '||(y( centroid( $geometry) ) + 0.5)||','||
'))')
```

Answer (score 7):

My answer comes late, but should help anyway...

When using the geometry generator, you must think like a CAD designer.

The following formula, based on X_DIM and Y_DIM fields, will do the trick just right. It creates a line with 4 points that makes a diamond shape then creates the rectangle boundary of it.

```
bounds(make_line( make_point( $x- ("X_DIM" /2),$y) , make_point( $x+ ("X_DIM" /2),$y) ,make_point( $x,$y- ("Y_DIM" /2)) , make_point( $x,$y+ ("Y_DIM" /2))  ) )
```

EDIT : even simpler, as suggested by @tudorbarascu, you can aswell make a diagonal with 2 points only and make the boundary of it.

[image: Example]

Comment: It would be simpler to just create the diagonal line (2 points) and create the bbox around it.

Comment: indeed ! Simple is beautiful :)

Answer (score 5):

Personally, in QGIS 3, I couldn't get the above bounds method to work (sorry Ian, didn't try yours). So, anyway, I just thought in more simple terms:

```
bounds(buffer($geometry, 500))
```

Replace 500 with your own square dimension

Comment: Wouldn't this create a circular buffer rather than a rectangular buffer? I don't see how this answers the question. Please [edit] your post to include more details about how this would create a rectangular buffer.

Comment: It creates a square bounding box around a circular buffer. The result is just a load of squares where the points were. I think that answers the question?

Comment: I stand corrected, I neglected to read the `bounds` part.

Comment: I have an issue very similar to the problem above. I need a rectangle which is 3.0km length by 3.58km width. I am also a complete beginner to QGIS. What would I need to type into the **Geometry generator** to get a rectangle of these dimentions?. Would I need to input this data within a Text file and upload the data in QGIS first, would be the **geometry generator** calculate it for me?

Comment: Super clever! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to draw a circle marker with

```
buffer(  $geometry ,0.01)
```

This works also and draws a fixed polygon

```
 geom_from_wkt( 'POLYGON (( 377 380, 613 474, 343 115, 377 380 ))')
```

I thought that building a polygon around a point would work like this:

```
geom_from_wkt('POLYGON ((
$x-0.01 $y-0.01,
$x-0.01 $y+0.01,
$x+0.01 $y+0.01,
$x+0.01 $y-0.01
$x-0.01 $y-0.01))')
```

However, it doesn't. I may have a wrong syntax or then Geometry generator does not support calculations inside WKT, which is actually not surprising. Making a buffer and taking an envelope of the buffered geometry was the next thing I was considering but Geometry generator does not have Envelope function.

Comment: "Envelope function" : have a try with "bounds()" > see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I used the following:

```
rotate(make_line(
make_point(x($geometry)-"W"/2000,y($geometry)+"L"/2000),
make_point(x($geometry)+"W"/2000,y($geometry)+"L"/2000),        
make_point(x($geometry)+"W"/2000,y($geometry)-"L"/2000),
make_point(x($geometry)-"W"/2000,y($geometry)-"L"/2000),
make_point(x($geometry)-"W"/2000,y($geometry)+"L"/2000)
),"angle")
```

the starting geometry is point layer
W and L are the side dimensions in mm, project is in m
with the field "angle" the multiline rotates accordingly
geometry type is to set on LineString/MultiString