# How to create rectangular buffers around points in QGIS with Python?

Tags: pyqgis, buffer

Using the following code from a similar question ([How to create square buffers around points in QGIS with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/210295/how-to-create-square-buffers-around-points-in-qgis-with-python)) I am able to create square buffers (5x5 degree cells) around my points.

However, I also need to make 5x10 degree cells and 10x20, is there a way I can modify the following code to get this result?

Code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer&field=x:real&field=y:real&field=point_id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'square_buffer',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    point = feat.geometry().asPoint()
    new_feat = QgsFeature()
    new_feat.setAttributes([i, point[0], point[1], feat.id()])
    tmp_feat = feat.geometry().buffer(1000, -1).boundingBox().asWktPolygon()
    new_feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(tmp_feat))
    prov.addFeatures([new_feat])

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

Comment: Perhaps these answers can help http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216394/draw-rectangle-with-a-given-size-height-length-from-attribute-table.

Comment: Cheers, I can add length and width columns to my points table, but I was wondering if there is a way to build that into the tidy code above. I can get squares with this line:    

 tmp_feat = feat.geometry().buffer(1000, -1).boundingBox().asWktPolygon()


Yet I feel that there should be a way to add into the buffer function some kind of length and width specifications. However I am finding it hard to locate this.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to modify the code for getting "rectangular" buffers (please, see my answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the code is modified as follow, it can be obtained rectangular buffers as you expected.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer&field=x:real&field=y:real&field=point_id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'rectangular_buffer',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    point = feat.geometry().asPoint()
    new_feat = QgsFeature()
    new_feat.setAttributes([i, point[0], point[1], feat.id()])
    bbox = feat.geometry().buffer(1000, -1).boundingBox()
    tmp_feat = bbox.asWktPolygon()
    xmin1,ymin1,xmax1,ymax1 = bbox.toRectF().getCoords()
    xmin2,ymin2,xmax2,ymax2 = feat.geometry().buffer(2000, -1).boundingBox().toRectF().getCoords()
    p1 = QgsPoint(xmin1, ymax2)
    p2 = QgsPoint(xmax1, ymin2)
    new_ext = QgsRectangle(p1,p2)
    new_tmp_feat = new_ext.asWktPolygon()
    new_feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(new_tmp_feat))
    prov.addFeatures([new_feat])

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

After running the code at the Python Console of QGIS, I got:

[image]