# Using centroid point to generate polygon using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, polygon, geometry, centroids

Is this possible to generate polygons from points (which are centroids of future polygon)? I got shapefile with ~250 points + they have got two attributes: length and width.

I don't need complete workaround I need tip on how this can be achieved.

Below is sketch picture of what I want to achieve.
[image]

Comment: You have an answer for QGIS here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217218/how-to-create-rectangular-buffers-around-points-in-qgis-with-python/217239#217239. You can try to adapt this code for arcpy.

Comment: Im gonna check this. Thank you! But if anyone has something more arcpy related please post your ideas.

Comment: Add geometry attributes and Create 2 copies of your points. Calculate Shape using arcpy.Point(pointx-w/2,pointy-L/2). This will create lower left points. Similarly calculate upper right points. Merge, dissolve to create multipoint, minimum bounding geometry envelope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import arcpy

fc = r'X:\centroids.shp'
heightfield = 'height'
widthfield = 'width'
outfile = r'X:\rectangles2.shp'

points = [i for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,['SHAPE@XY',heightfield,widthfield])]
features = []

for point in points:
    lowerleft = arcpy.Point(point[0][0]-point[2]/2, point[0][1]-point[1]/2)
    lowerright = arcpy.Point(point[0][0]+point[2]/2, point[0][1]-point[1]/2)
    topleft = arcpy.Point(point[0][0]-point[2]/2, point[0][1]+point[1]/2)
    topright = arcpy.Point(point[0][0]+point[2]/2, point[0][1]+point[1]/2)
    features.append(arcpy.Polygon(arcpy.Array([lowerleft,lowerright,topright,topleft])))

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features,outfile)
```

[image]