# How to create a irregular buffer around a point?

Tags: qgis

I need to create an buffer around a point which is 3.58km x 3.0km. i.e I need two sides of the buffer to be 3.58km long and the other two sides to be 3.0km --> making a rectangular shape. I am finding this task difficult as the buffer area is not an equal area. does anyone know how to do this?

I have tried to, however There are a few issues I face with this.

Firstly, my coordinate reference system is in degrees not meters. Would it be accurate if I was to convert the CRS from WGS84 to once which uses meters instead of degrees. then type in the specific dimensions I want --> save the shapefile and then convert it to WGS84.

Secondly The buffer tool does not have a viable option to input two data points. Would I need to save the data points (i.e 3.58km x 3.0km) In Excel and save it as a text file then upload it and enter that data set into the buffer tool?

Comment: Draw a 0.58 km long line oriented as you need it, then use a rectangular buffer of 3 km. Also, you can convert as you like.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to explain what you mean by an "irregular buffer" and how this differs from an ellipse.

Comment: I hope this edit better explains my issue?

Comment: Not really. The problem here is that a buffer around a point is regular (a circle), so you want an irregular regular shape. You need to provide a graphic to make your meaning clear.

Comment: @Vince, I think the question is about to create a simple rectangular around the point.

Comment: @Vince would creating that simple rectangle provide me with two edges of 3.0km and the other two 3.58km?

Comment: Have you seen these solutions: [How to create rectangular buffers around points in QGIS with Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217218/how-to-create-rectangular-buffers-around-points-in-qgis-with-python) and [Draw rectangle with a given size (height/length) from attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216394/draw-rectangle-with-a-given-size-height-length-from-attribute-table?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Comment: I am too much of a beginner to use python, The second link helps a lot, But I am still trying to understand what to input into _geometry generator_ to create such rectangle

Comment: 1) create an ellipse of the required size; 2) create a bounding box, 3) create a buffer from the bounding box and you will succeed...