# Creating multiple polygons within one geometry generator using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geometry-generator

Is it possible to create multiple `geom_from_wkt()` elements like [Using QGIS Geometry Generator to get rectangle from point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194519) **in a single** geometry generator symbol layer?

Comment: Do you mean a single symbol layer as in one geometry generator layer (so the expression must generate multiple elements), or a single symbology layer (so they appear as a group)? For the latter you could just add multiple geometry generator layers within the one symbology using the + button... offset them as required.

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late for OP, maybe useful for others who wind up here:
This can be achieved with `collect_geometries(geometry1,geometry2…)`

Available since QGIS 3.10: https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog310/index.html#feature-new-expression-functions

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
rotate(make_line(
make_point(x($geometry)-"W"/2000,y($geometry)+"L"/2000),
make_point(x($geometry)+"W"/2000,y($geometry)+"L"/2000),        
make_point(x($geometry)+"W"/2000,y($geometry)-"L"/2000),
make_point(x($geometry)-"W"/2000,y($geometry)-"L"/2000),
make_point(x($geometry)-"W"/2000,y($geometry)+"L"/2000)
),"angle")
```

- where a polygon is created with a series of points within a make_line function
- "W" and "L" are the sides of the rectangle in mm
- the same polygon is rotated based on the field "angle"
- the geometry is a point vector layer