# Creating flat end buffer using geometry generator in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, buffer, qgis-2.18

I'm new to GIS software and I've been introduced to QGIS 2.18 as part of my internship.

I was tasked with creating new styles for the company's maps, however I've encountered a problem with one of the requested styles.

I was to create a style for a line that would create a buffer for a line and then apply a gradient depending on the angle of the line (This part I manage to get using geometry generator). However, it returns the line buffers as an oval and I would like it to be flat ended (take a shape as a rectangle).

I am aware that v.buffer.distance allows for creation of flat-ends but I'm hoping for the same result but by using geometry generator so that it could be saved as a style.

[image: Buffer, and bounds(Buffer example]

The picture above shows what I've managed to create the buffer($geometry,0.05) vs the bounds method in [Using QGIS Geometry Generator to get rectangle from point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194519/using-qgis-geometry-generator-to-get-rectangle-from-point)

To specify again, I want to rectangularize(?) the result I got from buffer($geometry, 0.05)

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Using QGIS Geometry Generator to get rectangle from point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194519/using-qgis-geometry-generator-to-get-rectangle-from-point), the `bounds` method might be useful depending on how you created your geometries :)

Comment: I did have a look at the post. While I couldn't get all of them to work (probably because they are for points), the one with bounds worked and generated a polygon that has flat ends but it goes from corner to corner. I will edit the question and insert a picture of examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a virtual layer that transforms your line into a polygon. You would then style this new layer.

Go to `layer / add layer / add - edit virtual layer` and type the following query. Rename `a` by your line layer, and add fields as needed. `0.01` is the 1/2 buffer size (here in degrees) and the ending `0 / 1` is for right or left side.

You can at the same time compute the line azimuth (angle between the horizontal and the 1st/last point of the line, expressed in radians)

```sql
select id, 
 st_union(ST_SingleSidedBuffer(geometry,0.01,0) ,  ST_SingleSidedBuffer(geometry,0.01,1)),
 st_azimuth(st_startpoint(geometry),st_endpoint(geometry)) azim 
from a
```

[image]

Comment: This method works perfectly, but it seems to upset my fill a bit, my fill was a gradient that would be dependent on how the line was drawn. Do you know of a way to keep that information so that the gradient fill would follow that angle? (Currently it seems to follow the line but whatever the point is higher in y axis seem to be classified as the zero point, so if i draw top point first then bottom it would result in the same gradient as when I draw bottom point first then top)

Comment: @MateuszDąbkowski see edit. You can compute the line azimuth at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

In **QGIS 3.2**, there are additional buffer functions you can use to style your lines. Each function has a set of properties you could set such as the number of segments and, most importantly in your case, setting the **join style** (i.e. round, miter (flat) or bevel). These are not available in QGIS 2.x but if you can get access to the latest QGIS version, you could follow the steps below:

---

1. At the moment, there is only the `single_sided_buffer` function which uses the join style property. This creates a buffer on either side of the line but we can use two of these and split the difference in width so that it will *look* like a single buffer. We can use an expression like:

   ```
   single_sided_buffer( geometry, distance, segments, join)
   ```

   where:

   - `geometry` - Current geometry
   - `distance` - Buffer distance (positive values = left of line; negative values = right of line)
   - `segments` - Number of segments used to represent circles. This is *supposed* to be optional but for some reason, I need to include it otherwise it won't work.
   - `join` - Join property (1 = round, 2 = miter and 3 = bevel)

---

2. Add a symbol layer for the geometry generator and we will create one side of the buffer with an expression like:

   ```
   single_sided_buffer( $geometry, 0.05, 0, 2)
   ```

   [image: Symbology]

---

3. Add another and use negative values:

   ```
   single_sided_buffer( $geometry, -0.05, 0, 2)
   ```

---

4. This should give the appearence of a *rectangular* buffer (the red lines are the original line features):

   [image: Buffer]

Comment: I was going to suggest this. But with curved lines it does not look very good, the ends do not line up.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this. I assume that if I created a style in 3.2 it wouldn't work in 2.18? If not, I will keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto - You're right, it does look 'blocky'. I wonder if there's additional properties which could smooth this out.

Comment: @MateuszDąbkowski - Most welcome! Chances are styles created from QGIS 3.2 would not work in 2.28, although the opposite _might_ be fine.