# Setting flat end caps for polygon using Geometry Generator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, polygon-creation, geometry-generator

I'm trying to buffer a line using Geometry Generator in QGIS:

```
buffer($geometry, 3)
```

However although I've set the Simple Fill join style to miter I can't get the ends of the buffer to be flat.

[image]

I wanted to use a polygon for styling (rather than having the line width set to 6 map units) because it's much easier to have a semi-transparent fill with a consistent border and a line fill effect.

Is there any way to set the end cap for polygon styles or using expressions? I notice `single_sided_buffer()` has a parameter for join style but `buffer()` does not.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Creating flat end buffer using geometry generator in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289229/creating-flat-end-buffer-using-geometry-generator-in-qgis)

Comment: Aha. For some reason that didn't come up at all when I searched, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of the current QGIS 3.22 (LTR) the `buffer()` function in Expression Builder now has parameters for join type, cap type etc. So by using for example `buffer($geometry,2, cap:='flat')` one can have a flat-ended geometry generated buffer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have line vector file that you want to buffer, you can input it to QGIS tool ["Buffer"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#buffer) (`Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools`)

[image: buffer tool window]

The parameter you want to change is called `'END_CAP_STYLE'`. Setting it to `1 — Flat` should give you the desired result.

Comment: Is this in SQL? The parameter you refer to doesn't seem to exist with geometry generator expressions (for `buffer()`, anyhow).

Comment: I only just noticed the edit clarifying that this was for the vector geoprocessing tool. The entire point of using the geometry generator is to avoid creating a new, static layer so this doesn't address the question.