# QGIS Polygon buffer on only one side

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, symbology, buffer

I want to create a buffer on only one side of a polygon. When I create a buffer in the symbology tab in the layer properties, I get the following result:

[image]

I need a buffer that starts at the outline of the polygon and dos not overlap with the yellow filling. I need the result as a .qml file to be able to import it into another feature style.

Comment: single side buffer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/289229/creating-flat-end-buffer-using-geometry-generator-in-qgis

Comment: That looks like it's creating a buffer around a line feature not a polygon feature. Are you sure it's a polygon you're buffering?

Comment: yes, it's a polygon with a transparent filling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should buffer the polygon itself and not its outline.

Add a style `geometry generator` and not `outline: geometry generator` and call the buffer function `buffer($geometry,0.0001)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a transparency of 70% for the inner polygon, so the buffer can be seen. Is there also an option to only display the outer part of the buffer?

Comment: @Blabsl expand the style to `geometry generator/fill/simple fill` and then select `outline:simple line` instead of `simple fill`