# Fine-tuning curved text positioning

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling

I'm trying to label features using the geometry generator (QGIS 3.8). I used the following expression to build a simple circle :

```
buffer(centroid($geometry), 500)
```

In Placement i used **Using Perimeter (curved)**

The labeling is working pretty good except some of my features label are written **clockwise** and some **counterclockwise**. How could i control this rendering ?

Furthermore i would like the mid-point of my labeling string to be at the most northern point of the circle ...

How could i achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clockwise/counterclockwise fix, you can allow upside-down labels. In label rendering tab set `Show upside-down labels` to *allways*.

[image]

For centering the label to the north, I figure out a workaround based on [Using QGIS Geometry Generator to get rectangle from point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194519/using-qgis-geometry-generator-to-get-rectangle-from-point). Using geometry generator in label placement tab, you can create buffer of tiny polygon witch starts at such a place that the label is then rendered on top. Just adjust the buffer size to your needs.

```
buffer(geom_from_wkt( 
    'POLYGON(('|| 
        (x(centroid($geometry)))||' '||(y(centroid($geometry)) - 0.0001) ||','||
        (x(centroid($geometry)))||' '||(y(centroid($geometry)) + 0.0001) ||','||
        (x(centroid($geometry)) + 0.0001)||' '||(y(centroid($geometry)) - 0.0001) ||','||
    '))'
    ),
    0.3
)
```

[image]

Note that geometry generator for label placement is available from version QGIS 3.8

Comment: So where do you put that `buffer` expression? Do you add a geometry generator symbol layer?

Comment: @csk No, in version 3.8 is geometry generator also for label placement (in Labels -> Placement tab)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that in your answer, otherwise people using the current LTR will have trouble understanding your answer.

Comment: Yes, but I followed the OP, where is mention use of geometry generator for label placement in version QGIS 3.8. For completeness, I added note to my answer.

Comment: @Oto i'm using indeed qgis 3.8 but i'm struggling using your expression ... where should i put it ? is it supposed to replace my former `buffer(centroid($geometry),500)`? how would my text be bended in that case ? What kind of units should be used in such expression ?

Comment: @snaileater Yes exactly, it is a replacement, you have tu put the expression to geometry generator in label placement tab. `buffer` function and units stay same so you can use `500`. But instead of yours `centroid($geometry)` it use `geom_from_wkt()` to create tiny triangle around centroid angled that way that the label is then rendered on top.

Comment: ok it's working, thanks ! ... but i'll need some time to understand **why** it is working ... lol

Comment: :) You can use the `geom_from_wkt()` part in symbology geometry generator, which gnerate the polygon as symbol, so you can see what is happening in the background when you use the expression for labels.